# Get data from MySQL for API call using AJAX in Laravel

Tags: mysql, ajax, database, laravel, api

I need to get data(recipe IDs) from MySQL to make API calls to display in my view. I'm trying to use AJAX in Laravel, and I don't know where to start. If anyone can point me to the right direction, that would be great!

This is the API that I'm working with. It has a key but I am also confused as to why it's not included in the URL, just the parameter for the ID:
https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/recipes/{id}/information

What my database look like:
[The recipe ID need to concatenate with API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5E7A.png)

My custom.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function recipeDatabase() {
        var $key = "**KEY**"
        var $recipeId = **need to get from database**;

        $.ajax({
            url:"https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/recipes/" + $recipeId +"/information?includeNutrition=true",
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            data: {

            },
            success: function (data) {
                $(".display").html(data);
            }
        })
    }
recipeDatabase();
})
```

My view is in my saved.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Saved Recipes</h1>
    <div class="display">

    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: You could inject the recipes into the view and render the JS with the recipe ID. You can also make an AJAX call to an endpoint in your application and get the recipe iD, then call this other API.

Comment: are you just going to use one id at a time from the db or all ids from the database table to make the api call?

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi I'm trying to use all of the IDs from the database to make the api call. So once I'm in the saved.blade view, it should display all of the recipes

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to get all recipe ids, then you have to create a controller and have it return the ids to the view

```
public function getRecipeId()
{
    $recipe_ids =  json_encode(Recipe::pluck('id')->toArray());

    return view('recipes', compact('recipe_ids'));
}
```

Then you can set the element to hold that value as hidden, for example:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $recipe_ids }}" id="recipe_ids">
```

Then you can retrieve the value of that element with jquery and pass it into your ajax call to that api:

```
var $key = "**KEY**";
$.each(JSON.parse($('#recipe_ids').val()), function(idx, $recipeId){


    $.ajax({
            url:"https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/recipes/" + $recipeId +"/information?includeNutrition=true",
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            data: {

            },
            success: function (data) {
        //you have to find ways of displaying the response properly
                $(".display").html(data);
            }
        })
    });
```

Another method is to set an ajax call to the controller to retrieve the id:

```
public function getRecipeId()
{
    $recipe_ids =  Recipe::pluck('id')->toArray();
    return response()->json($recipe_ids);
}
```

And also afterwards make a call to that your external api for example:

```
$.get('/yourapi/path').done(function ($recipeIds) {
    $.each(JSON.parse($recipeIds), function(idx, $recipeId){
    var $key = "**KEY**";
    $.ajax({
            url:"https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/recipes/" + $recipeId +"/information?includeNutrition=true",
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            data: {

            },
            success: function (data) {
            //you have to find ways of displaying the response properly
                $(".display").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

One final way I would do this is simply to use Guzzle, You can install guzzle easily with composer and if you have it then your `getRecipeId` controller method might look like this:

```
public function getRecipeId()
{
    $recipes = [];
    $client = GuzzleHttp\Client()
    Recipe::pluck('id')->each(function($recipeId, $key) use (&$recipes){
       recipes[] = $client->get("https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/recipes/" + $recipeId +"/information?includeNutrition=true")->getBody()->getContent();
    });
    return view('saved', compact('recipes'));
}
```

If this is successful then you can display the data from the call when you access `$recipes` in the view.

> PS: These are for demos/explanation purpose, so you might need a little tweek. And also for those ajax call it will be good to handle situation where you have failure, and the same when using Guzzle.
>
> And sorry the reason I didnt post how to display this in the view is 1. I don't know the format of the response, and 2. You should explore laravel doc and try out how to render it. You can see the result of the call (in js) using console.log() and in laravel using dd();

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving a data and have to concatenate so you can manually deal with it using a function to create some table like:

```
function createTable(data) {
    table = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr>";
        table += "<td>" + data.data[i].id + "</td>";
        table += "<td>" + data.data[i].recipe_id + "</td>";
        table += "<td>" + data.data[i].created_at + "</td>";
        table += "<td>" + data.data[i].updated_at + "</td>";
        table += "</tr>";
    }
    ;
    $('.display').html(table);
};
```

In your sucess ajax call function:

```
success: function (data) {
                createTable(data);
                if (data.data.length == 0) {
                    $('.display').html(
                        "None data found"
                    );
                }
            },
```

Well, this works for me. Just do some console.log() to see how you can call your attributes and this should work.

Comment: this is good if you want to display table. But if I understood well, the OP wants to know how to retrieve id or ids from his own server's mysql and with the id make an api call to an external service...